# Why does downsample appear as a gray image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, downsampling

In the implementation of downsampling by a factor of 2 to the image, the downsampled image is gray. What should I do in order to add all of the color components to the downsampling implementation so that it will be a color image?

```
  I = imread('lena.gif','gif');
  [j k] = size(I)


  x_new = j./2;
  y_new = k./2;


  x_scale = j./x_new;
  y_scale = k./y_new;


  M = zeros(x_new,y_new);


  for count1 = 1:x_new
     for count2 = 1:y_new
     M(count1,count2) = I(count1.*x_scale,count2.*y_scale);
     end
  end


    figure,imshow(I);
    title('Original Image');
    M = uint8(M);
    figure,imshow(M);
    title('Downsample');
```

Comment: `M` has just one layer and there is no RGB information so it makes sense that the result is gray. You should work with all 3 layers if the input image.

Comment: How can I add RGB info to M then? I am new at image processing :/ @NKN

Comment: why wont you just use `imresize` ??

Comment: I am supposed to implement it, should not use built in functions @bla

Comment: well already by doing `./2` you might run into errors if `j` is an odd number etc... you need to use `round` or `floor` throughout your code...

Comment: now my only problem is to fix grey image I can fix that afterwards =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GIF images are what are known as **indexed** images.  This means that what you read in with `imread` are values that are **indices** to a colour map.  Each index generates a unique colour for you, and that's how GIF images are stored.  They choose from a predefined set of colours, and each pixel in the GIF image comes from one of the colours in the colour map.

You first need to convert the image into RGB, and you do that with [`ind2rgb`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2rgb.html).  However, you need to read in the colour map first with the two-output version of [`imread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html#btv1ptn-1).  You also will want to convert the images to `uint8` as good practice with [`im2uint8`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/im2uint8.html):

```
[X,map] = imread('lena.gif');
I = im2uint8(ind2rgb(X,map));
```

What you need to do next is what @NKN suggested.  You must apply the algorithm to all channels.

As such, simply make an output matrix that has three channels, and apply the algorithm to each plane independently.  If I can make a suggestion, when accessing pixels this way after you downsample, make sure you `floor` or `round` the image coordinates so you're not inadvertently specifying locations that aren't defined - things like (13.8, 25.5) for example.  Image pixel locations are integer, so you need to make sure the coordinates are integer too.

---

```
[X,map] = imread('lena.gif');
I = im2uint8(ind2rgb(X,map));

j = size(I,1); %// Change
k = size(I,2);

x_new = j./2;
y_new = k./2;


x_scale = j./x_new;
y_scale = k./y_new;


M = zeros(x_new,y_new,size(I,3)); %// Change


for jj = 1 : size(I,3) %// Change
   for count1 = 1:x_new
     for count2 = 1:y_new
        M(count1,count2,jj) = I(floor(count1.*x_scale),floor(count2.*y_scale),jj); %// Change
     end
  end
end


figure,imshow(I);
title('Original Image');
M = uint8(M);
figure,imshow(M);
title('Downsample');
```

---

To test this, I'm using the `mandrill` dataset that's part of MATLAB.  It is an indexed image with an associated colour map.  These are coincidentally stored in `X` and `map` respectfully:

```
load mandrill;
I = im2uint8(ind2rgb(X,map));
```

Running the modified code, I get these two figures:

[image]

[image]

Comment: the problem is the code he has does not down-sample!

Comment: Thank you so much! what if I don't use GIF? Then I do not need (X,map) part? @rayryeng

Comment: @Blu Correct.  Just do `I = imread('...');`.  However, if you want to make absolutely sure you get a RGB image each time, you can always check to see if the second output is non-empty.  Something like `[I,map] = imread('...'); if ~isempty(map), I = ind2rgb(I); end`  This will make sure that we create a RGB image regardless of there being a colour map associated with the image.

Comment: I applied the code you provided above but the original image and downsampling image are exactly same. Their size should be different but it is not =/ they are literally same @rayryeng

Comment: They shouldn't be.  I just tried this on a built-in image.  I'll upload results.

Comment: @Blu Check the update.  Also check the updated code.  I've updated some things.

Comment: I = imread('lena.png');

j = size(I,1); %// Change
k = size(I,2);

x_new = j./2;
y_new = k./2;


x_scale = j./x_new;
y_scale = k./y_new;


M = zeros(x_new,y_new,size(I,3)); %// Change


for jj = 1 : size(I,3) %// Change
   for count1 = 1:x_new
     for count2 = 1:y_new
        M(count1,count2,jj) = I(floor(count1.*x_scale),floor(count2.*y_scale),jj); %// Change
     end
  end
end


 figure,imshow(I);
title('Original Image');
M = uint8(M);
figure,imshow(M);
title('Downsample');

Comment: It is not working for .png image I copied and pasted your code. I think it is because of  
I = imread('lena.png');     It shows exactly same images for both..

Comment: @Blu PNG requires a colour map.  You must call the two output version of `imread`.  I can't reproduce your error....

Comment: [X,map] = imread('lena.png');
I = im2uint8(ind2rgb(X,map)); This is also giving error. But anyways thank you @rayryeng

Comment: Oh I realized that it is because of image processing toolbox! problem solved! sorry and thanks (= @rayryeng

Comment: :S `imread` uses the image processing toolbox... well I'm glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

When you read the original image it contains 3 layers, R-G-B (as suggested by @rayryeng:

```
[X,map] = imread('lena.gif');
I = ind2rgb(X,map);
size(I)

ans =

         768        1024           3
```

You should perform the down-sampling process on all the layers:

The code you provided does not down-sample. A simple downsampling example is as follows:

```
imshow(I(1:2:end,1:2:end,:))
```

Comment: That's not the full story.  You also need to read in the colour map from the GIF image too.  However, +1 for the major point of applying the algorithm to each plane.